# How to write repository test without executing query on db

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, phpunit, symfony4

I have spent my fare share of hours trying to create a proper Phpunit test for my repository function and still no success, so that's why I'm turning on you guys for help

I'm trying to write a test, which is testing my repository function, without connecting to database

I have this repository function (Symfony 4)

```
class RequestRepository extends EntityRepository
{
   public function getCompletedRequestByName($name)
        {
            $requestsStatuses = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
                ->join('r.domains', 'd', Join::WITH, 'r.id = d.request')
                ->where('r.name = :name')
                ->andWhere('r.status = :completed')
                ->setParameter('name', $name)
                ->setParameter('completed', 'COMPLETED')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getOneOrNullResult();
            return $requestsStatuses;
        }
}
```

And this is my test

```
public function testGetCompletedRequestByName()
{
    $entityM =
        $this->getMockBuilder(EntityManagerInterface::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMockForAbstractClass();

    $classMetaData =
        $this->getMockBuilder(ClassMetadata::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMockForAbstractClass();

    $repo = new RequestRepository($entityM, $classMetaData);
    var_dump($repo->getCompletedRequestByName('antrax.com'));
    die();
}
```

And the error I'm getting is

```
1) App\Repository\RequestRepositoryTest::testGetCompletedRequestByName
Error: Call to a member function select() on null
```

Can some one please help me out, how to write a test, which test my repository function, without connection to DB and executing any queries. If you need any additional informations, please let me know and I will provide! Thank you!

Comment: You basically need to adjust the mocked entity manager to return a mocked query builder and then check for calls to join, select etc.  It's a real pain the butt and can be fragile as any tweak will cause the test to fail.  Plus it does not really check if your query itself will return the expected data.  It's one reason why some folks just create a test database (perhaps using sqlite) and actually execute the query.

Comment: Hi, can you please make post an example code how to do it? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for my case. If any body need's it, this is how my test looks like

```
public function testGetCompletedRequestByName()
{

    $queryBuilder = $this->getMockBuilder(QueryBuilder::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(['setParameter', 'getQuery', 'getOneOrNullResult', 'join', 'andWhere', 'where'])->getMock();

    $queryBuilder->method('getQuery')->willReturnSelf();

    $queryBuilder->method('setParameter')->willReturnCallback(function ($field, $value) use ($queryBuilder){
        if ($field == 'name') {
            $this->assertSame('antrax.com', $value);
        } elseif ($field == 'completed') {
            $this->assertSame('COMPLETED', $value);
        }
        return $queryBuilder;
    });

    $queryBuilder->method('join')->willReturnCallback(function ($field, $alias, $operator, $cond) use ($queryBuilder){

        $this->assertSame('r.domains', $field);
        $this->assertSame('d', $alias);
        $this->assertSame(Join::WITH, $operator);
        $this->assertSame('r.id = d.request', $cond);

        return $queryBuilder;
    });

    $queryBuilder->method('where')->willReturnCallback(function ($cond) use ($queryBuilder){

        $this->assertSame('r.name = :name', $cond);
        return $queryBuilder;
    });

    $queryBuilder->method('andWhere')->willReturnCallback(function ($cond) use ($queryBuilder){

        $this->assertSame('r.status = :completed', $cond);
        return $queryBuilder;
    });

    $repositoryMock =
        $this->getMockBuilder(RequestRepository::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['createQueryBuilder'])->getMock();

    $repositoryMock->method('createQueryBuilder')->willReturnCallback(function ($alias) use ($queryBuilder){
        $this->assertSame('r', $alias);
        return $queryBuilder;
    });

    $repositoryMock->getCompletedRequestByName('antrax.com');
}
```

Comment: Congrats on figuring it out.  Not seeing where you are testing the QueryBuilder::getQuery call and of course you really should mock up a Query for it and verify getOneOrNullResults is called.  And while completely off topic it's interesting you have a plural for your return statuses but only at most one status will be returned.